# rsync excluding cache directories

Tags: rsync

I use rsync as a backup tool to my external hard disk. However I want to save time by no copying useless cache files of several programs. I want to achieve this by omitting every file which is somewhere in the tree under a folder called Cache, cache or cache2 In fact any variations of names which hint to a cache folder in the full path.

They can be in paths like:

```
.cache/google-chrome/Default/Cache/1e1cb5d5222c54c4_0
.cache/mozilla/firefox/smifthya.default/cache2/entries/15444D7EEEAF61418021BC35F25FD997974458B5
```

So I try to exclude those cache files from being synched by the following lines so far not successful.

What I tried so far:

```
rsync -va --delete --exclude={*Cache*, *cache*} /var/www/ $MYEXDISK/www

rsync -va --delete --exclude '*cache*' /var/www/ $MYEXDISK/www

rsync -va --delete --exclude 'cache*' /var/www/ $MYEXDISK/www

rsync -va --delete --exclude={Cache*, cache*} /var/www/ $MYEXDISK/www
```

Can anybody tell me the corect syntax to exclude any file, in which's path there is a variation of Cache or cache?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you want:

> `set -B` - brace expansion mode (**possibly optional**)
>
> `rsync -va --delete --exclude={**/Cache*,**/cache*} /var/www/ $MYEXDISK/www`

See [YoLinux](http://man.yolinux.com/cgi-bin/man2html?cgi_command=rsync) then seach for `INCLUDE/EXCLUDE PATTERN RULES`. The relevant info is:

> use '**' to match anything, including slashes.

### Extra info

The `{...,...,...}` is referred to as brace expansion.
It has very specific rules.

1. Spaces are not allowed.

   - See (good) `echo --exclude={foo,bar}` => `--exclude=foo --exclude=bar`
   - vs. (bad) `echo --exclude={foo, bar}` => `--exclude={foo, bar}`
2. A single element expansion will not work.

   - See (bad) `echo --exclude={foo}` => `--exclude={foo}`
3. Sometimes quoting the results helps, sometimes it breaks things. Try both.

   - See (good) `echo --exclude=\'{foo,bar}\'` => `--exclude='foo' --exclude='bar'`
4. If your file names have spaces you need to muli-quote the string

   - See (good) `echo --exclude=\'{"foo bar",baz}\'` => `--exclude='foo bar' --exclude='baz'`
   - vs. (bad) `echo --exclude={'foo bar',baz}` => `--exclude=foo bar --exclude=baz`
   - vs. (bad) `echo --exclude=\'{foo bar,baz}\'` => `--exclude='{foo bar,baz}'`